# How to create a string array in MATLAB?

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I would like to pass a vector of strings from C++ to MATLAB. I have tried using the functions available such as `mxCreateCharMatrixFromStrings`, but it doesn't give me the correct behavior.

So, I have something like this:

```cpp
void mexFunction(
    int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
    int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
   vector<string> stringVector;
   stringVector.push_back("string 1");
   stringVector.push_back("string 2");
   //etc...
```

The problem is how do I get this vector to the matlab environment?

```cpp
   plhs[0] = ???
```

My goal is to be able to run:

```matlab
>> [strings] = MyFunc(...)
>> strings(1) = 'string 1'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Storing a vector of strings as a char matrix requires that all of your strings are the same length and that they're stored contiguously in memory.

The best way to store an array of strings in MATLAB is with a cell array, try using `mxCreateCellArray`, `mxSetCell`, and `mxGetCell`.  Under the hood, cell arrays are basically an array of pointers to other objects, char arrays, matrices, other cell arrays, etc..

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    int rows = 5;
    vector<string> predictLabels;
    predictLabels.resize(rows);
    predictLabels.push_back("string 1");
    predictLabels.push_back("string 2");
    //etc...

    // "vector<string>" convert to  matlab "cell" type
    mxArray *arr = mxCreateCellMatrix(rows, 1);
    for (mwIndex i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
        mxArray *str = mxCreateString(predictLabels[i].c_str());
        mxSetCell(arr, i, mxDuplicateArray(str));
        mxDestroyArray(str);
    }
    plhs[0] = arr;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Why `mxDuplicateArray `? If you do `mxSetCell(arr, i, str);`, you can also remove `mxDestroyArray(str);`.